# Using a variable in file_get_contents php

Tags: php

I'm trying to make a dynamic webpage.  I have the title for each page in its own file and I was trying to use file_get_contents() to get the title, but I'm not sure how to use a variable in the path.  This is what I've tried.

```
<?php
         $movie= $_GET["film"];
         $title= file_get_contents('/movies/moviefiles/.$movie./info.txt');

 ?>

 <h1><?= ($title) ?> </h1>
```

Comment: Learn about [concatenation](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.string.php) or about [interpolation of variables in strings](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.parsing)

Comment: Then watch out in case anybody tries to use a film title of `../../etc/passwd` or similar

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You aren't concatenating the strings properly.

Try:

```
$title= file_get_contents('/movies/moviefiles/'.$movie.'/info.txt');
```

The same can be done with double-quotes, too:

```
$title= file_get_contents("/movies/moviefiles/$movie/info.txt");
```

The difference is that variables aren't interpolated within single quotes. If they're in double-quotes, the actual value of the variable will be used.

And read more about string concatenation here: http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.string.php

Answer (score 1):

You need to use double quotes `"` when you want to use variables inside a string or concatenate using the `.`.

```
$foo = "world";
print "hello $foo";
print 'hello '.$foo;
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code should be like this:

```
<?php
$movie= $_GET["film"];
$title= file_get_contents('/movies/moviefiles/'.$movie.'/info.txt');
?>
<h1><? echo $title; ?> </h1>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't work with variable with simple quote.

if you want to use variable, use double quote

```
$title= file_get_contents("/movies/moviefiles/$movie/info.txt");
```

More information on these quotes : http://www.php.net/manual/fr/language.types.string.php

Answer (score 0):

```
$title= file_get_contents("/movies/moviefiles/$movie/info.txt");
```